# magento - add links to footer but not to top navigational menu

Tags: magento, hyperlink, footer

I want to add links to the footer - such as Customer service etc.. I do this by editing the CMS static block, footer links. However when I do this, they also appear in the very top menu.

Anyone know how to add links to the footer without them appearing in the top navigational menu?

Regards and thanks,
Fiona

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding links to the static block will not show them on the top of the site, unless you have repeated the Block at the top of the template.

The footer links are controlled through XML and the Static Block.

There are multiple ways to achieve your need. You can include a custom block and create your own links under the CMS static blocks.

Could you expand on what exactly you are trying to achieve?

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('your_cms_block_identifier')->toHtml() ?>
```

Insert the above into the template. Create a CMS Static block with 'your_cms_block_identifier' and create your links

Comment: <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('your_cms_block_identifier')->toHtml() ?>

Insert the above into the template. Create a CMS Static block with 'your_cms_block_identifier' and create your links.

Comment: Sid, thanks a million for that.. i'll take a look at the template... and check the top.. hopefully that will fix my problem! thanks again.

Comment: I did so as it is written, but the menu does not show. What else could it be?

Comment: It should work. We use it all the time. Try clearing the cache.